# Which function in Java is like the LIKE Operator in Lotusscript

Tags: java, lotusscript

is there a function for Java that works like the [LIKE operator in lotusscript](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/3090ec8617414f1b85256c54004c3b1b?OpenDocument)?
Or is there something I can easily configure, so it works the same?

Or do i have to build it my own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Function on what class?  java.lang.String?  Java's an object-oriented language.  Could be as simple as a String compare, or a regex, or a full-blown parser.  I'd assume you'll have to build your own.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Java has regular expressions which trump the simplistic `like` of LotusScript.

Comment: @duffymo yes, on a String

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know, that there is regex. But i have a NotesApplication build with LotusNotes and have to rebuild it in Java. So i have the same data and need a function that works the same as that LIKE operator.

Comment: Regular expressions are your best bet.  Your users will have to know about regular expressions in order to pass in patterns for matching - that will be painful.  Write your own class that encapsulates the subset of behavior that you want.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. The closest thing you can have on Java will be regex most likely the **[matches method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)** from the class String.

But it will require you to use regular expression instead of wildcards as the lotusscript function you mentioned.

Here is a reference to a [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

As for this example on the doc you show from lotusscript:

two-digit numbers from 1 to 100 that end in 3 and don't begin with 2

```
For x = 1 To 100
  If CStr(x) Like "[!2]3" Then Print x
Next x
```

The equivalent in java would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=1;i<=100;i++){
        if ( String.valueOf(i).matches("[^2]{1}3") ){
            System.out.println( i );
        }
    }
}
```

The output would be: `13 33 43 53 63 73 83 93`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the regular expression in java. 
Here is the link.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Below tutorial have some working examples as well.

You can use 
java.util.regex.Pattern and  java.util.regex.Matcher , above link has those examples as well.